# How to get plain text version of rendered page?

Tags: phantomjs

I am running PHP PhantomJs and I am looking to get plain text version of webpage. 
Right now i am using :
   echo $response->getContent();
Which brings whole html source code of rendered page, I dont need that. I need to get rendered plain text from page.